# how 'not in' command works?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: see this image and tell me what is the result?]

how does 'not in' sql command work in set membership?
I don't understand.

```
SELECT course_id
FROM section
WHERE semester='Spring' and course_id not IN
(SELECT course_id
 from section
WHERE semester='Fall')
```

Comment: It's like `IN` - only the opposite.

Comment: but i don't understand when i use it in set of membership

Comment: you can see the image .what will be the result of this query??

Answer (score 0):

This would return the course 222. The query gets all the courses offered in the fall, and then gets all the IDs of the courses offered in the spring. If the ID is found in the list of courses offered in the spring, then that course is not included in the final result. In this case, course 111 is filtered out.